# Regex to select first occurrence of phone number from string

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to create a regex that will grab the first occurrence of a phone number from this string:

```
<font color="#848484">Transferor(s)</font>
<br />Harzuz Holdings Ltd<br />Ontario Potato Inc&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;905-791-7735<br />
<em>Clark Packaging Products Inc</em>
<p>
</p>Pres: Jay Burstein<br />8 Tracey Blvd, Unit 2<br />Brampton, Ontario<br />L6T 5R9<p>
</p>
<font color="#848484">Transferee(s)</font>
<br />2470347 Ontario Inc&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;416-223-4403<br />
```

The phone numbers are always consistently formatted like this: `999-999-9999`.  The problem I am having is that my regex is grabbing both phone numbers from my string when I only want to grab the first one.  This is what I have tried so far:

`(\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d) ?` returns multiple phone numbers

`(\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d) {1}` also returns multiple phone numbers

What regex can I use to select the first phone number?  And what regex can I use to select the second phone number?

I am using uBot which is a type of windows automation software.  This is the code that I have tried, but neither of these lines are working for me:

```
set(#phone1, $find regular expression(#x, "\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d ?"), "Global")
set(#phone2, $find regular expression(#x, "(\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d)\{1\}"), "Global")
```

Comment: You should specify the regular expression language. The answer will be completely based on that.

Comment: Actually, it depends. What programming language are you using? PHP, for example, has the preg_match and preg_match_all ...

Comment: Sorry about that, I am using the .NET regex engine..

Comment: just grab the first one out of the matches collection.

Comment: Thanks @DanielA.White.  Sorry for the basic question, but could you please explain how I do that?

Comment: @DanielAttard please share how you are using the regex.

Comment: i don't reconize the language - is that powershell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87669/discussion-between-danielattard-and-daniel-a-white).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a multiline-string, it has newline characters, you can use that to differentiate between the first occurrence (which is in a line that end with the newline symbol: `\n`) and the last one:

```
(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})(?=.*\n)
```

Tested in an [environment that tests regex in .Net](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)

Comment: this works of course, but it returns both phone numbers and I only want the first one.  I don't understand how match collections work.  Can you tell me how I isolate the first occurrence?

Comment: @DanielAttard if it returns both - it means that you have `\n` at the end of the string. In that case you can add to the lookahead the `<em>` from the next line of the first occurrence: `(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})(?=.*\n<em>)`

Answer (score 1):

Now, I think you know that how to identify a telephone number but the problem is how do you know which one is the first one?

The better way than saying the word **"first"**, I may advice you to bind your telephone number pattern to the keyword **"Transferor"** instead, this is more semantics, thus we get a pattern

```
(?<=Transferor)[\s\S]*(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})
```

**Explanation**

`(?<=Transferor)` check if there is a word "Transferor" before,

`[\s\S]*` any string including newline,

`(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})` telephone number.

Now the telephone number of Transferor is stored in `$1` variable.

Note that regex above is just a standard form, please edit it according to .NET.